# Neural Network classifying data in 3 categories with no rules

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Can somebody tell me if it is possible through NN ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, classification can be performed for the new products on the basis of product features.

Look into `One-Vs-All Classification/ Multi-class Classification` method. I suggest you to divide the dataset you have into 70-80% `training` and 20-30% `testing` dataset. Then, train the neural network only with `training` dataset and test it's accuracy on `testing` dataset.  This way you can measure how well your network will perform on unseen/new products. Finally, when you achieve desired performance/accuracy, save the neural net model and test it on new products.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible.

But only through experimentation (simulated on the old products you already observed) will you be able to tell if your trained NN (or any other model you choose) produces good predictions.

Comment: You might enjoy this visual explanation of machine learning
http://www.r2d3.us/visual-intro-to-machine-learning-part-1/